# Android sdk manager can't download packages other than lollipop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

i installed Android Studio and i couldn't find any package other than 5.1.1 to download and here is the SDK Manager log

[image: as showed in picture]

> Fetching http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>   Fetched Add-ons List successfully Fetching URL:
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml Done
>   loading packages. Fetching
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml Fetched
>   Add-ons List successfully Fetching URL:
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml Done
>   loading packages.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I used ultra surf but it looks like doen't work with android studio

Comment: This may help: Go to `SDK Manager` > `Tools`> `Options` and **Uncheck** `Force https://...`

Comment: solved using hotspot shield .. thank you